# Deploy de projeto Django no Heroku com erros

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, heroku

Ao tentar fazer deploy do meu projeto Python usando Django no Heroku, estou recebendo o seguinte erro.

```
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 273 bytes | 273.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     Python has released a security update! Please consider upgrading to python-3.6.7
remote:        Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> Found python-3.7.0, removing
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.4
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing dependencies with Pipenv 2018.5.18…
remote:        Installing dependencies from Pipfile…
remote:        An error occurred while installing django-render-block==0.5! Will try again.
remote:        An error occurred while installing pipenv==9.0.3! Will try again.
remote:        Installing initially–failed dependencies…
remote:        Success installing django-render-block==0.5!
remote:        Success installing pipenv==9.0.3!
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> release, web
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 336.9M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:  !     Warning: Your slug size exceeds our soft limit (336 MB) which may affect boot time.
remote:        Released v10
remote:        https://erpgetcode.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
remote: Running release command...
remote: 
remote: Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:   File "manage.py", line 23, in <module>
remote:     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
remote:     utility.execute()
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
remote:     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 224, in fetch_command
remote:     klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 36, in load_command_class
remote:     module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
remote:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 14, in <module>
remote:     from django.db.migrations.autodetector import MigrationAutodetector
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 11, in <module>
remote:     from django.db.migrations.questioner import MigrationQuestioner
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/questioner.py", line 9, in <module>
remote:     from .loader import MigrationLoader
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 8, in <module>
remote:     from django.db.migrations.recorder import MigrationRecorder
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 9, in <module>
remote:     class MigrationRecorder:
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 22, in MigrationRecorder
remote:     class Migration(models.Model):
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 87, in __new__
remote:     app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 249, in get_containing_app_config
remote:     self.check_apps_ready()
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 131, in check_apps_ready
remote:     settings.INSTALLED_APPS
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
remote:     self._setup(name)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
remote:     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 107, in __init__
remote:     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
remote:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
remote:   File "/app/djangosige/configs/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
remote:     from .settings import *
remote:   File "/app/djangosige/configs/settings.py", line 2, in <module>
remote:     from decouple import config, Csv
remote: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'decouple'
remote: Waiting for release.... failed.
To https://git.heroku.com/erpgetcode.git
   47ea108..cd777ac  master -> master
```

meu requirements.txt

```
django==2.0.5
dj-database-url==0.5.*
python-decouple==3.1
pytz==2018.3
reportlab==3.4.*
six==1.11.*
cryptography>=2.3
lxml==4.2.*
pyOpenSSL==17.5.*
signxml==2.5.*
```

Procfile

```
release: python3 manage.py migrate
web: gunicorn erpgetcode.wsgi
web: gunicorn erpgetcode:app
```

runtime.txt

```
 python-3.6.4
```

Pipfile

```
[[source]]

url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"


[packages]

astroid = "==1.5.3"
certifi = "==2018.1.18"
chardet = "==3.0.4"
colorama = "==0.3.9"
django = "*"
django-render-block = "==0.5"
django-templated-email = "*"
"flake8" = "==3.5.0"
idna = "==2.6"
isort = "==4.2.15"
lazy-object-proxy = "==1.3.1"
mccabe = "==0.6.1"
pew = "==1.1.2"
pipenv = "==9.0.3"
psutil = "==5.3.1"
pycodestyle = "==2.3.1"
pyflakes = "==1.6.0"
pylint = "==1.7.4"
pytz = "==2017.3"
requests = "==2.18.4"
"urllib3" = "==1.22"
virtualenv = "==15.1.0"
virtualenv-clone = "==0.2.6"
wrapt = "==1.10.11"


[dev-packages]



[requires]

python_version = "*"
```

Eu tentei isso

```
$ pip3 install python-decouple
```

Mas disse que já está instalado

```
Requirement already satisfied: python-decouple in /home/rafael/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (3.1)
```

Também tentei mudar a versão do Python para 3.6.7, mas aconteceu o mesmo.

Alguém tem ideia do que está errado?

Comment: O python-decouple não está listado no seu pipfile, tente desinstalar ele e instalar novamente mas utilizando o pipenv install. Quando você instala a dependência direto pelo pip, ele não fica salvo no pipfile.